# Angular Module is not available (md-chip-select)

Tags: javascript, angularjs

> im a newbie at angular and I try to get this result https://codepen.io/boo0330/pen/EjOWgg,

but my console keep saying to me :

"Failed to instantiate module **demoapp** due to:
Error: [$injector:modulerr] Failed to instantiate module md.chips.select due to:
Error: [$injector:nomod] Module '**md.chips.select**' is not available! You either misspelled the module name or forgot to load it. If registering a module ensure that you specify the dependencies as the second argument."

and a lot more of lines related to this error, what am i doing wrong ? 
I already tried to reorder my script but has no effect

```js
var demoApp = angular.module("demoapp", ['ngAnimate', 'md.chips.select' /*, "material.components.icon", "ngMaterial",'material.core', 'material.components.autocomplete'*/ ])

demoApp.controller('mainCtrl', ["$scope", function($scope) {
  console.log("Controller initializing...");
}]);

demoApp.controller('chipsCtrl', ["$scope", function($scope) {
  $scope.fruitNames = ["Apple"];
}]);
demoApp.controller('chipsSelectCtrl', ["$scope", function($scope) {

  $scope.sItems = [{
    name: "Mini Cooper",
    id: 0
  }, {
    name: "Lexus IS250",
    id: 1
  }, {
    name: "Ford F150",
    id: 2
  }, {
    name: "Toyota Prius",
    id: 3
  }, {
    name: "Porsche 911",
    id: 4
  }, {
    name: "Ferreri 488",
    id: 5
  }];

  $scope.myItems = [$scope.sItems[4], $scope.sItems[5]];
}]);

demoApp.controller('cChipsSelectCtrl', ["$scope", "$timeout", function($scope, $timeout) {

  $scope.selectedCoutries = [];
  $scope.countiesList = [{
    country: "Taiwan",
    id: 0
  }, {
    country: "United States",
    id: 1
  }, {
    country: "United Kingdom",
    id: 2
  }, {
    country: "Hong Kong",
    id: 3
  }];

  $timeout(function() {
    console.log("Set focus");
    angular.element(".chips-input")[0].focus();
  }, 500);
}]);
```

```html
<html ng-App="demoapp">

<head>
  
  <title>NgApp</title>
</head>

 <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.4.0/angular.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.4.0/angular-animate.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.4.0/angular-route.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.4.0/angular-aria.js"></script>
<script src = "https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angular_material/1.0.0/angular-material.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/TEST1.js"></script>

<body ng-controller="mainCtrl">
  <div class="row">
    <div ng-controller="chipsSelectCtrl">
      <span>You have selected: {{myItems}} </span>
      <md-chips-select ng-model="myItems" select-items="sItems" main-title="name"></md-chips-select>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row" style="margin-top:60px;">
    <div ng-controller="cChipsSelectCtrl">
  <span>Where have you been: {{selectedCoutries}} </span>
  <md-chips-select ng-model="selectedCoutries" select-items="countiesList" main-title="country id"></md-chips-select>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're missing a whole batch of code. The code pen example that you are trying to copy is dependant on code from [another pen](https://codepen.io/boo0330/pen/NqEpjm)  which you can't copy or link to here.

If you manually copy the additional CSS and JavaScript across, it looks horrible, but it works...

```js
(function(){
var MD_CHIPS_SELECT_TEMPLATE = '\
  <md-chips-wrap class="md-chips-select" ng-class="{ \'md-focused\': isFocused() }"> \
    <md-chip ng-repeat="chip in mdChipItems" class="md-chip"> \
      <span class="md-chip-content">{{chip.mainTitle}} </span>\
      <button class="md-remove" ng-click="removeFromChips(chip)"> \
        <span class="remove"> \
          <svg version="1.1" x="0px" y="0px" viewBox="0 0 24 24" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" fit="" height="100%" width="100%" preserveAspectRatio="xMidYMid meet" style="pointer-events: none; display: block;"><g><path d="M19 6.41l-1.41-1.41-5.59 5.59-5.59-5.59-1.41 1.41 5.59 5.59-5.59 5.59 1.41 1.41 5.59-5.59 5.59 5.59 1.41-1.41-5.59-5.59z"></path></g></svg> \
        </span> \
      </button> \
    </md-chip>\
    <div class="md-chip-input-container"> \
      <input type="text" \ class="chips-input" \
        ng-focus="onInputFocus($event)" \
        ng-model="chipInput" \
        ng-blur="onInputBlur()" \
        ng-keydown="onKeyDown($event)" />\
      </md-chip-input-container> \
    </div> \
    <md-select-list ng-show="selectActive" ng-style="{top: ytop, left: xleft}"> \
      <md-select-item-wrapper ng-repeat="item in mdSelectItems" ng-class="{\'active\': !isInChips(item)}" ng-show="inputQuery(item)" ng-click="toggleItem(item)"> \
        <md-select-item-title>{{item.mainTitle}}</md-select-item-title> \
        <span ng-show="!isInChips(item)" style="float:right; margin-right:20px;"> \
          <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="12" height="12" viewBox="0 0 24 24"> \
            <path d=\"M0 0h24v24h-24z\" fill=\"none\"/> \
            <path d=\"M9 16.17l-4.17-4.17-1.42 1.41 5.59 5.59 12-12-1.41-1.41z\"/> \
          </svg> \
        </span> \
      </md-select-item-wrapper> \
    </md-select-list> \
  </md-chips-wrap>';


var MD_CHIPS_SELECTBOX_TEMPLATE = '\
  <md-select-list ng-show="selectActive" class="ng-hide-add" ng-style="{top: ytop, left: xleft}"> \
    <md-select-item-wrapper ng-repeat="item in mdSelectItems" ng-class="{\'active\': !isInChips($index)}"/*ng-show="isInChips($index)" */ng-click="toggleItem($index)"> \
      <md-select-item-title >{{item.mainTitle}}</md-select-item-title> \
      <span> \
        <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="24" height="24" viewBox="0 0 24 24"> \
          <path d=\"M0 0h24v24h-24z\" fill=\"none\"/> \
          <path d=\"M9 16.17l-4.17-4.17-1.42 1.41 5.59 5.59 12-12-1.41-1.41z\"/> \
        </svg> \
      </span> \
    </md-select-item-wrapper> \
  </md-select-list>';
angular.module('md.chips.select', [])
.service("mdItems", function(){

})
.directive('mdChipsSelect', ["$document", "$compile", "$log", "$timeout", function($document, $compile, $log, $timeout){
  return {
    restrict: 'E',
    replace: false,
    controller: "mdChipsCtrl",
    template: function(element, attrs) {
   
      return MD_CHIPS_SELECT_TEMPLATE;
    },
    require: "?ngModel",
    scope: {
      ngModel: '=',
      selectItems: '=',
      mainTitle: '@'
    },
    link: function (scope, element, attrs) {

      scope.mdChipItems = scope.ngModel;
      scope.mdSelectItems = scope.selectItems;

      if(scope.mainTitle == null) {
        scope.mainTitle = "title";
      }
      var subString = scope.mainTitle.split(' ');
      
      angular.forEach(scope.mdChipItems, function(obj, key){
        obj.mainTitle = '';
        angular.forEach(subString, function(field, fkey){
          if(obj[field]!=null){
            obj.mainTitle += obj[field].toString();
            obj.mainTitle += ' ';
          }
        });
      });
      
      angular.forEach(scope.mdSelectItems, function(obj, key){
        obj.mainTitle = '';
        angular.forEach(subString, function(field, fkey){
          if(obj[field]!=null){
            obj.mainTitle += obj[field].toString();
            obj.mainTitle += ' ';
          }
        });
      });

      $document.bind('click', function(e){
        var clicked = e.target.nodeName;
        if( e.target.nodeName != "MD-SELECT-ITEM-WRAPPER"
            && e.target.nodeName != "MD-SELECT-ITEM-TITLE" 
            && e.target.nodeName != "INPUT" 
            && e.target.nodeName != "MD-ICON"
            && (e.target.nodeName != "SPAN" || e.target.attributes.getNamedItem("class").value.indexOf("md-chip-content") == -1)
            && (e.target.nodeName != "SPAN" || e.target.attributes.getNamedItem("class").value.indexOf("remove") == -1)
          ){
          
            $timeout(function(){
              // Close select panel
              scope.selectActive=false;
            }, 0)
        }
      });
      
      scope.onInputFocus = function(event){
        scope.ytop = (event.currentTarget.offsetTop+35) +'px';
        scope.xleft = (event.currentTarget.offsetLeft) + 'px';
        scope.selectActive = true;
        scope.focus = true;
      }

      scope.onInputBlur = function(){
        scope.focus = false;
      }

      scope.isFocused = function(){
        return scope.focus;
      }

      scope.onKeyDown = function(e) {
        if(e.which==13) { //Enter
          if(scope.chipInput && scope.chipInput != "" && scope.ngModel.indexOf(scope.chipInput) == -1)
            this.ngModel.push(scope.chipInput)
          scope.chipInput = "";
        }
        else if(e.which == 8){
          if (scope.chipInput == null || scope.chipInput == ""){
            this.ngModel.pop();
          }
        }
      }
      scope.removeFromChips = function(item){
        var chipIndex = scope.ngModel.indexOf(item);
        scope.ngModel.splice(chipIndex, 1);
      }

      scope.isSelectActive = function(){
        return scope.selectActive;
      }

      scope.addToChips = function(obj){
        scope.ngModel.push(obj);
        scope.chipInput = "";
        scope.chipInput.focus=true;
      }

      scope.toggleItem = function(item) {
        
        var chipIndex = scope.ngModel.indexOf(item);
        console.log(scope.ngModel);
console.log(item);
        console.log(chipIndex);
        if(  chipIndex != -1 ) {
          scope.removeFromChips(item);

        } else {
          scope.addToChips(item);
        }
      } 

      scope.isInChips = function(item) {
        return scope.ngModel.indexOf(item) == -1;
      }  
      scope.inputQuery = function(item) {

        if(!scope.chipInput ||
          scope.chipInput == "" || angular.lowercase(item.mainTitle).indexOf(angular.lowercase(scope.chipInput))!=-1)
          return true;
        else
          return false;
      }
    }
  }
}])
.controller("mdChipsCtrl", ['$scope', function($scope){
  $scope.focus = false;
  $scope.selectActive = false;
  $scope.mdChipItems = [];
  $scope.mdSelectItems = [];
  $scope.currentMdSelectItems = [];
  $scope.ytop = 0;
  $scope.xleft = 0;
}])
})();

(function() {
  var demoApp = angular.module("demoapp", ['ngAnimate', 'md.chips.select']);

demoApp.controller('mainCtrl', ["$scope", function($scope) {
  console.log("Controller initializing...");
}]);

demoApp.controller('chipsCtrl', ["$scope", function($scope) {
  $scope.fruitNames = ["Apple"];
}]);
demoApp.controller('chipsSelectCtrl', ["$scope", function($scope) {

  $scope.sItems = [{
    name: "Mini Cooper",
    id: 0
  }, {
    name: "Lexus IS250",
    id: 1
  }, {
    name: "Ford F150",
    id: 2
  }, {
    name: "Toyota Prius",
    id: 3
  }, {
    name: "Porsche 911",
    id: 4
  }, {
    name: "Ferreri 488",
    id: 5
  }];

  $scope.myItems = [$scope.sItems[4], $scope.sItems[5]];
}]);

demoApp.controller('cChipsSelectCtrl', ["$scope", "$timeout", function($scope, $timeout) {

  $scope.selectedCoutries = [];
  $scope.countiesList = [{
    country: "Taiwan",
    id: 0
  }, {
    country: "United States",
    id: 1
  }, {
    country: "United Kingdom",
    id: 2
  }, {
    country: "Hong Kong",
    id: 3
  }];

  $timeout(function() {
    console.log("Set focus");
    angular.element(".chips-input")[0].focus();
  }, 500);
}]);

})();
```

```css
@-webkit-keyframes fadeIn {
  0% {
    opacity: 0;
  }

  100% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
}

@keyframes fadeIn {
  0% {
    opacity: 0;
  }

  100% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
}

.fadeIn {
  -webkit-animation-name: fadeIn;
  animation-name: fadeIn;
}

@-webkit-keyframes fadeOut {
  0% {
    opacity: 1;
  }

  100% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
}

@keyframes fadeOut {
  0% {
    opacity: 1;
  }

  100% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
}

.fadeOut {
  -webkit-animation-name: fadeOut;
  animation-name: fadeOut;
}

.ng-hide-add {
  -webkit-animation:0.5s fadeOut ease; 
  animation:0.5s fadeOut ease; 
}

.ng-hide-remove { 
  -webkit-animation:0.5s fadeIn ease; 
  animation:0.5s fadeIn ease; 
}

.md-chips-select{
  box-shadow:0 1px #e0e0e0;
}
.md-chips-select.md-focused {
  box-shadow: 0 2px rgb(63, 81, 181);
}

md-chips-select .md-chip {
  background: #e0e0e0;
  color: #424242;
}

.md-chips-select {
  display: block;
  font-family: RobotoDraft, Roboto, 'Helvetica Neue', sans-serif;
  font-size: 13px;
  padding: 0 0 8px 0;
  vertical-align: middle;
  cursor: text; }
  .md-chips-select:after {
    content: '';
    display: table;
    clear: both; }
  .md-chips-select .md-chip {
    cursor: default;
    border-radius: 16px;
    display: block;
    height: 32px;
    line-height: 32px;
    margin: 8px 8px 0 0;
    padding: 0 8px 0 12px;
    float: left; }
    .md-chips-select .md-chip .md-chip-content {
      display: block;
      padding-right: 4px;
      float: left;
      white-space: nowrap; }
      .md-chips-select .md-chip .md-chip-content:focus {
        outline: none; }
    .md-chips-select .md-chip .md-chip-remove-container {
      display: inline-block;
      margin-right: -5px; }
    .md-chips-select .md-chip .md-chip-remove {
      text-align: center;
      width: 32px;
      height: 32px;
      min-width: 0;
      padding: 0;
      background: transparent;
      border: none;
      box-shadow: none;
      margin: 0;
      position: relative; }
      .md-chips-select .md-chip .md-chip-remove md-icon {
        height: 18px;
        width: 18px;
        position: absolute;
        top: 50%;
        left: 50%;
        -webkit-transform: translate3d(-50%, -50%, 0);
                transform: translate3d(-50%, -50%, 0); }
  .md-chips-select .md-chip-input-container {
    display: block;
    line-height: 32px;
    margin: 8px 8px 0 0;
    padding: 0 8px 0 12px;
    float: left; }
    .md-chips-select .md-chip-input-container input:not([type]), .md-chips-select .md-chip-input-container input[type="email"], .md-chips-select .md-chip-input-container input[type="number"], .md-chips-select .md-chip-input-container input[type="tel"], .md-chips-select .md-chip-input-container input[type="url"], .md-chips-select .md-chip-input-container input[type="text"] {
      border: 0;
      height: 32px;
      line-height: 32px;
      padding: 0; }
      .md-chips-select .md-chip-input-container input:not([type]):focus, .md-chips-select .md-chip-input-container input[type="email"]:focus, .md-chips-select .md-chip-input-container input[type="number"]:focus, .md-chips-select .md-chip-input-container input[type="tel"]:focus, .md-chips-select .md-chip-input-container input[type="url"]:focus, .md-chips-select .md-chip-input-container input[type="text"]:focus {
        outline: none; }
    .md-chips-select .md-chip-input-container md-autocomplete, .md-chips-select .md-chip-input-container md-autocomplete-wrap {
      background: transparent;
      height: 32px; }
    .md-chips-select .md-chip-input-container md-autocomplete md-autocomplete-wrap {
      box-shadow: none; }
    .md-chips-select .md-chip-input-container md-autocomplete input {
      position: relative; }
    .md-chips-select .md-chip-input-container input {
      border: 0;
      height: 32px;
      line-height: 32px;
      padding: 0; }
      .md-chips-select .md-chip-input-container input:focus {
        outline: none; }
    .md-chips-select .md-chip-input-container md-autocomplete, .md-chips-select .md-chip-input-container md-autocomplete-wrap {
      height: 32px; }
    .md-chips-select .md-chip-input-container md-autocomplete {
      box-shadow: none; }
      .md-chips-select .md-chip-input-container md-autocomplete input {
        position: relative; }
    .md-chips-select .md-chip-input-container:not(:first-child) {
      margin: 8px 8px 0 0; }
    .md-chips-select .md-chip-input-container input {
      background: transparent;
      border-width: 0; }
  .md-chips-select md-autocomplete button {
    display: none; }

@media screen and (-ms-high-contrast: active) {
  .md-chip-input-container, md-chip {
    border: 1px solid #fff; }
  .md-chip-input-container md-autocomplete {
    border: none; } }
md-select-list {
  max-height: 220px;
  overflow: auto;
  position: absolute;
  width:300px;
  background: white;
  box-shadow: 0px 0.5px 4px 0px rgba(1,1,1,0.3);
  display:block;
}

md-select-list::-webkit-scrollbar {  
  width: 7px;
}  
md-select-list::-webkit-scrollbar-track {  
  background-color: transparent;  
}  
md-select-list::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {  
  background-color: rgba(200,200,200, 0.5);  
  opacity: 0.5;
  border-radius: 5px;
}  
md-select-list::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb:hover {  
  background-color: #aaa; 
}  

md-select-item-wrapper {
  height: 27px;
  font-size:15px;
  line-height: 2em;
  padding: 3px 10px;
  font-family: RobotoDraft, Roboto, 'Helvetica Neue', sans-serif;
  font-weight: 300;
  color: #505050;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #e7e7e7;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  overflow: hidden;
  display:block;
  cursor: pointer;
}

md-select-item-wrapper.active {
  color: #def1f0;
  background-color: #009788;
}

.md-remove {
  height: 32px;
  width: 32px;
  padding: 0;
  background: transparent;
  border: none;
  box-shadow: none;
  margin: 0;
  position: relative;
}
.remove {
  height: 18px;
  width: 18px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  -webkit-transform: translate3d(-50%, -50%, 0);
  transform: translate3d(-50%, -50%, 0); }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.4.0/angular.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.4.0/angular-animate.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.4.0/angular-route.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.4.0/angular-aria.js"></script>
<script src = "https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angular_material/1.0.0/angular-material.min.js"></script>

<html ng-App="demoapp">

<head>
  
  <title>NgApp</title>
</head>

<body ng-controller="mainCtrl">
  <div class="row">
    <div ng-controller="chipsSelectCtrl">
      <span>You have selected: {{myItems}} </span>
      <md-chips-select ng-model="myItems" select-items="sItems" main-title="name"></md-chips-select>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row" style="margin-top:60px;">
    <div ng-controller="cChipsSelectCtrl">
  <span>Where have you been: {{selectedCoutries}} </span>
  <md-chips-select ng-model="selectedCoutries" select-items="countiesList" main-title="country id"></md-chips-select>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thank's a lot ! i didn't see it like that :o ; i just figured out that there are codepen settings...